how to write this snowflake statement in teradata?
I have a calculation with the iff statement in snowflake query as
 IFF(
    count(id) = 0
  , NULL
  , round(
        100 * sum(
                  case 
                      when ind = TRUE 
                      then 1 
                      else 0 
                  end)
        / count(id)
      , 2
    )
  ) as id_perc

please help me to write this in teradata.
The below statement worked after adding the CAST.
CASE WHEN
COUNT(id) = 0
THEN NULL
ELSE ROUND(
    100.0 * CAST(SUM(
        CASE WHEN
            ind = 1
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS FLOAT) / CAST(COUNT(id) AS FLOAT), 2
) END AS id_perc


Both SUM and COUNT are returning INTEGER values and the constant 100 is BYTEINT, so the integer division is truncating to a whole number before passing a value to ROUND. CAST at least one term to NUMBER or FLOAT so the division does not truncate.

@Fred Great added the working solution to the question.
